# Angular 2: Mulitple select with no default value

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, angular2-forms, multiple-select

I have a multiple select dropdown with just 2 options. I want it to have no default selected item. Currently, its default is the first item in the list which is `Rebadge`. I want it to be just the placeholder. Below are my html and typescript

```js
export class Filters {
  staff: any[];
  type: any[];
}

export class ProductListFilterComponent implements OnInit {
  selected = new Filters();
  typeOptions = [
    "Rebadge",
    "Only Once"
  ];
  
  constructor( private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute ){
    this.selected.type = [];
  }
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((params: Params) => this.queryParamsHandler(params)   )
    
  queryParamsHandler(params?: Params) {
    if (params['type'] && params['type'] !== '') {
      this.selected.type = params['type'];
       $('#typeOption').dropdown('set selected', params['type']);
    } else {
      $('#typeOption').dropdown('clear');
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<app-select [aria-label]="'Type'"
            [id]="'typeOption'"
            [panelClass]="'filter multiple fluid search'"
            [placeholder]="'Select Multiple...'"
            [multiple]="true"
            [selected]="selected.type"
            (change)="selected.type = $event">
    <option *ngFor="let type of typeOptions" [value]="type">{{ type }}</option>
</app-select>
```

Comment: Hey in html before for loop you can give something like <option selected value="">select</option> and in onchange() you can change the selected value

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a "placeholder" for a `<select>` element in HTML.

What is usually done is a disabled selected option.

Like:

```html
<select>
  <option selected disabled>And your answer is?</option>
  <option >Yes!</option>
  <option >No.</option>
  <option >Maybe...</option>
</select>
```

I'm not used to Angular, so I can't say... But you now know what to look for.